# Showing Logcat message on screen orientation change

Tags: android, orientation, android-logcat

I want to know when the orientation changes on my device using Logcat but it is not showing me any output (I'm using Android Studio). I've added the `screenSize` attribute to my `AndroidManifest.xml` but this doesn't fix the issue. Below is my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.danishrehman.orientationchangenotification" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity

            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"

            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

And here is my Java code:

```
package com.example.danishrehman.orientationchangenotification;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.util.Log;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        if(newConfig.orientation==Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
        {
            Log.d("LIFECYCLE","Welcome to Landscape Orientation");
        }
        else if (newConfig.orientation==Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
        {
            Log.d("LIFECYCLE","Welcome to Portrait Orientation");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your code with `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` and I could see proper logging in Android Studio Logcat. Sounds silly, but could you check what Log Level you have chosen in your Logcat window? As in your code, you have used `Log.d(...)` it should be visible only if you have chosen your Log Level in Logcat window as `Verbose` or `Debug` .

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You may check if the activity has been recreated, this is: the screen's orientation has changed.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            //probably orientation change
            Log.d("LIFECYCLE", "Orientation has changed!");
        }
    }
}
```